# Is there some way to get more details about this RecyclerView error: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I think the issue is something to do with the ads being inserted into the `RecyclerView` as this is a very simple list I have. But how can I get more information about it?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 11(offset:11).state:30 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{24e81e64 VFED.... .F....ID 0,0-540,742 #7f09017c app:id/mylist}, adapter:com.mopub.nativeads.MoPubRecyclerAdapter@224f5b32, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@43f4083, context:MyActivity@385fae15
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5654)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html You are trying to get item at position 11 on a list or array containing 11 items.

Comment: I get that, but this is kind of internal to the `RecyclerView`, none of my code is on the stacktrace. I'm guessing something is being updated wrong and since it only seems to happen to my free users, I'm guessing it has to do with the wrapped adapter MoPub puts. That is why I want to know how to get more details.